# Spring-boot Application Throwing Error on Actuator Port

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my **Java** application, I have kept the server port at: 8090
And the property `management.port=9080`

Now, in my browser, when I open a random link (http://localhost:9080) on the actuator port, my application throws the following error:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
>   23/11/2018:18:47:54.350 [http-nio-9080-exec-1]    E  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]                --- Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap

Whereas, when I put `management.port=8090` (same as the server port), this error is not thrown when I open a random link.

Is there a way to add a default request handler on the actuator port when it is different from the server port in a spring boot application?

Comment: Can you show your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that, but could you tell me what you're looking for? I have added the jackson dependency.

Comment: Your spring-boot version and jackson dependency which you just confirmed is there.

Comment: `<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>`

Comment: See [Add DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver to child context](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10560). Try upgrading to `1.5.16.RELEASE`

Answer (score 2):

In a standalone application, the Actuator HTTP port defaults to the same as the main HTTP port. To make the application listen on a different port, set the external property: **management.server.port.** To listen on a completely different network address (such as when you have an internal network for management and an external one for user applications), you can also set **management.server.address** to a valid IP address to which the server is able to bind.